# SQL to get OLD and NEW value mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Consider below tables

```
Create table t1 (n1 number identity, v1 varchar);
Create table t2 (n1 number identity, v1 varchar);
```

N1 in both tables are identity columns

Table t1 values are as below

---

```
|   N1   |    V1   |
|--------|---------|
|    1   |    A    |
|    2   |    B    |
|    3   |    C    |
-------------------
```

Now when I insert T1 table values into T2, I need to collect mapping between T1.N1 and T2.N1

Mapping of old N1 identity value and new N1 identity value.

Say, if in T2 identity values are created as below, I need to know what is the new T2.N1 value corresponding to old T1.N1 value.

---

```
|   N1   |    V1   |
|--------|---------|
|    6   |    A    |
|    7   |    B    |
|    8   |    C    |
-------------------


Old N1 = 1, New N1 = 6
Old N1 = 2, New N1 = 7
Old N1 = 3, New N1 = 8
```

What's the best way to achieve this in Oracle and MS SQL server? Programmatically or in a query? Without doing any table alterations.

I tried below method but it's not possible

### Oracle

```
Create type mapping_object is object (n1 number, n2 number);
Create type mapping_tab is table of mapping_object;

Insert into T2 (v1) 
select v1 from T1 
returning T2.n1, T1.n1 bulk collect into mapping_tab;
```

### SQL server

```
Declare @mapping_tab is table (n1 int, n2 int)

Insert into T2 (v1) 
Output inserted.n1, T1.n1 into @mapping_tab
Select v1 from T1
```

Comment: What `I need to collect mapping` mean? Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: n2 field does not exist from your Oracle example code. Still, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry. Updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new field to t2 to keep the tables linked, also allow you set a foreign key constraint.

```
Create table t2 (n1 number identity, v1 varchar, t1_n1 number);
```

and do

```
Insert into T2 (v1, t1_n1) 
Select v1, n1 from T1
```

Comment: Any other possibilities?, i cannot add new columns to the tables.